# Is it possible to quantify over SMT models?

Tags: z3, smt

I need to check whether every satisfying instance of some smt problem has a matching instance from some other smt problem. 
i.e. "forall instances of A exists instances of B s.t. ...." where A and B are sat models generated from some smt-lib code.

I've been thinking about this a lot but can't figure how to do it

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example? That is, include `A` and `B`,  specify the "matching" condition, etc.